# TreeView control renders as a <div>, causing an unwanted line break

Tags: asp.net, html, css, treeview

I'm trying to create a layout like so:

[image]

On the left hand side I want to add an ASP.NET `TreeView` control.  Unfortunately, it seems to render as a div, so it causes a line break.  I don't think I can use `display:inline`, as this doesn't seem to work:

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" style="display:inline;"
            onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" 
            ontreenodepopulate="TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate" 
            ontreenodeexpanded="TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded">
            <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" />
    </asp:TreeView>
```

My markup is as follows:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="filters">

    </div>
    <div id="dMiddle">
    <span id="sTreeView">
     <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" style="display:inline;"
            onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" 
            ontreenodepopulate="TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate" 
            ontreenodeexpanded="TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded">
            <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" />
    </asp:TreeView>
    </span>
    <span id="sGrid">eventually a grid...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is the `TreeView` causes a line break instead of staying in its span (or div or wherever I put it).

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use three `<div>`s (rather than the `<span>`s you have now).  Like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="filters">
        Some other stuff goes up here
    </div>
    <div id="dMiddle">
        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"
                onselectednodechanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged" 
                ontreenodepopulate="TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate" 
                ontreenodeexpanded="TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded">
                <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" />
        </asp:TreeView>
    </div>
    <div id="sGrid">
        Eventually a Grid goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Then all you need is a little CSS on your `<div>`s:

```css
#sGrid, #dMiddle { display:inline-block; }
#dMiddle { float:left; }
```

The first line there makes sure your dMiddle and sGrid `<div>`s stay on the same line together (no forced line break).

The second line is optional, and just floats the `TreeView`'s `<div>` to the left (It seems to line the two inline `<divs>`s up nicely).